# Remove Subview of UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

im running the same piece of code over and over when the user presses a button. If the user presses the button an image appears over the button, if they press it again the image is removed from the buttons subview.

here is my code:

```
 UIImageView *overlay = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"OverlayImage.png"]];

    NSString *senderstag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", buttonFromSender.tag];
    if([[dictonaryOfImagesToDelete allKeys] containsObject:senderstag]){
        [[buttonFromSender subviews]makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]; 
    }
    else{
    [buttonFromSender addSubview:overlay];
    }
    NSString *imageName = [[NSString alloc]init];
    imageName = [arrayWithImageNames objectAtIndex:buttonFromSender.tag];

    [imagesToDelete addObject:imageName];

    [dictonaryOfImagesToDelete setObject:imagesToDelete forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", buttonFromSender.tag]];
```

Im using a dictionary to keep track of which buttons have been pressed. instead of the imageview over the button being removed, it removes the whole button. How can i get it just to remove the imageview and not the button?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display different image for a button state u can directly initialize the button with to load a picture in that state.
say for example Enabled/Disabled, or Selected/Deselected(normal)

```
UIButton* myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];    
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"My Image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"My Other Image"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG Img"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

References:

Background Image:
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/backgroundImageForState:

Button Image:
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setImage:forState:

Comment: the image is just a overlay. you can still see most of the original image behind it.

Comment: And they are user images, so i cant photoshop them

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up making the UIImageview of the overlay, a UIButton. This allowed to set actions for it. Here is the code that is used:

```
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"OverlayImage.png"];
    UIButton *overlay = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    overlay.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 150);
    [overlay setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [overlay addTarget:self action:@selector(removeSelectedImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    overlay.tag = buttonFromSender.tag;


    [buttonFromSender addSubview:overlay];

    NSString *imageName = [[NSString alloc]init];
    imageName = [arrayWithImageNames objectAtIndex:buttonFromSender.tag];

    [imagesToDelete addObject:imageName];

    [dictonaryOfImagesToDelete setObject:imageName forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", buttonFromSender.tag]];
```

this set up the new UIButton

then to get rid of the UIButton i did this:

```
-(IBAction)removeSelectedImage:(id)sender{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
[button removeFromSuperview];
NSString *tag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", button.tag];
NSString *deleteWhat = [[NSString alloc]init];
deleteWhat = [dictonaryOfImagesToDelete objectForKey:tag];
[imagesToDelete removeObject:deleteWhat];
[dictonaryOfImagesToDelete removeObjectForKey:tag];
}
```